# How to replace columns in sparse Matrix Scipy

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a Matrix A and B with the identical 2d dimensions 
A - is a zeros Matrix  , from B I want to take just a first column and to replace first A.col[0] by B.col[0].

I write

```
data_sims = np.zeros((data.shape[0],data.shape[1]))
data_sims = sparse.csr_matrix(data_sims).tocoo()
```

I tried smth like that, but it's useless

```
data_sims.getcol(0).toarray = data.getcol(0).toarray()
```

I even tried to use hstack but again I get error 
    "ValueError: blocks must be 2-D"but they are identical 2-D sizes, what I'm missing? plz , help me.

```
data_sims = hstack(data.getcol(0).toarray(),data_sims)
```

Comment: The title sounds like you trying to change values in a sparse matrix.  But your example is trying to write values FROM a sparse matrix on to a regular array.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a column to column:

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

# Target matrix
A = np.zeros((2, 2))

# Some sparse matrix
B = sparse.csr_matrix([[5, 6], [7, 8]]).tocoo()

# Assign the first column from B into A
A[:, 0] = B.tocsc()[:, 0].todense().ravel()
```

This prints:

```
[[ 5.  0.]
 [ 7.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a 2d numpy array of zeros, not a matrix or sparse matrix.

```
In [782]: x = np.zeros((3,2),int)
In [783]: x.getcol(0)
....
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getcol'
```

Such an array does not have a `getcol` method; that's something that's defined form a sparse matrix.

You access columns of an array with indexing.  The result is a 1d array.  If you want to set the column you need to provide compatible values, such as another 1d array or list of the correct length.

```
In [784]: x[:,0]
Out[784]: array([0, 0, 0])
In [785]: x[:,0] = [1,2,3]
In [786]: x
Out[786]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0]])
```

A sparse matrix does have a `getcol`:

```
In [801]: M = sparse.csr_matrix([[1,0],[0,2],[2,0]])
In [802]: M
Out[802]: 
<3x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [803]: M.getcol(0)
Out[803]: 
<3x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [804]: M.getcol(0).toarray()
Out[804]: 
array([[1],
       [0],
       [2]], dtype=int32)
In [805]: x[:,0] = M.getcol(0).toarray()
....
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)
```

Because `M` is a sparse matrix, it is 2d, and `getcol` also produces a 2d sparse matrix.  Even when converted to dense array the result is 2d (3,1).  In this it imitates the `np.matrix` subclass.

By rules of broadcasting, (3,) is not compatible with (3,1).  ((1,3) is compatible).

`ravel` or flatten corrects that:

```
In [806]: x[:,0] = M.getcol(0).toarray().ravel()
In [807]: x
Out[807]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [2, 0]])
```

`csr` implements indexing, so this also works:

```
In [810]: x[:,0] = M[:,0].toarray().ravel()
```

For `coo` format, e.g. `Mo = M.tocoo()`, the `getcol` is necessary.

There are other ways of matching shapes.  For example if `x` was `np.matrix` rather than array, its column selection would be (3,1)

```
In [814]: X= np.matrix(x)
In [816]: X[:,0] = M[:,0].toarray()
```

Indexing with a list, `x[:,[0]]` or slice would also generate the 2d column.

In part, this is the same sort of array/matrix compatibility issue that has come up several times recently, but the use of sparse matrix adds a twist.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Didactic Example of "A" Method

Came here hoping for an answer, and wanted to try the following.
I was happy to find that this "numpy intuitive method" worked.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as ss

m1 = np.array([[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]])
m2 = np.array([[11, 14, 17], [12, 15, 18], [13, 16, 19]])

print(m1, '\n')
print(m2, '\n')

m1 = ss.csc_matrix(m1)
m2 = ss.csc_matrix(m2)

m1 = ss.hstack([m1[:, 0], m2[:, 1], m1[:, 2]])

print(m1.todense())
```

Output:

```
[[1 4 7]
 [2 5 8]
 [3 6 9]]

[[11 14 17]
 [12 15 18]
 [13 16 19]]

[[ 1 14  7]
 [ 2 15  8]
 [ 3 16  9]]
```